# IntelliJ IDEA 14 does not recognize spacebars templates

Tags: meteor, intellij-idea, syntax-highlighting, handlebars.js, spacebars

I am writing a [simple meteor app](http://philipmjohnson.github.io/ics-syllabus/) and finding that IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4 (with the Meteor and Handlebars plugins installed and enabled) does not recognize spacebars templates:

[image]

After googling, I tried `File > Invalidate Caches/Restart` but this did not work.

I also find that when I run `Code > Reformat Code`, the resulting indentation is not correct. I assume both problems are related.

Here is an even simpler illustration of the problem:

[image]

How can I debug this?

Comment: According to your screen shot, `if` block has not been closed properly. `{{#if currentUser}} ... {{/if}}`

Comment: I don't show the entire file in the screen shot, but I believe the `if` block is indeed closed properly. Here is the [source](https://github.com/philipmjohnson/ics-syllabus/blob/master/client/templates/home/home.html). Notice that the screenshot also shows an `each` block that is marked by IntelliJ as an error, but is clearly closed two lines down.

Comment: I scan your source carefully and find that every spacebars `{{...}}` miss the indent. I will post an answer to show it more clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I find the really tricky syntax error in my IntelliJ IDEA 14.
The main problem is the space between `{{` and `#` or `/`.
`{{#if currentUser}}` is right in syntax but `{{ #if currentUser }}` is wrong.
Alike, user `{{/if}}` instead of `{{ /if }}`.
So the spacebars usage is really strict here. Actually, there should be no extra spaces.

```
<template name="home">
    {{#if currentUser}}
        <div class="template-home">
            <div class="well">
                <form class="form-inline syllabus-chooser">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <select name="syllabusChooser" id="syllabusChooser" class="form-control">
                            <option value="0">(Select a syllabus to edit)</option>
                            {{#each syllabusSelectors}}
                                <option value="{{ value }}">{{ label }}</option>
                            {{/each}}
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" id="syllabusChooserButton" class="btn btn-default">Edit</button>
                </form>
            </div>

            {{#if displayID}}
                <div class="well">
                    {{#autoForm collection="Syllabuses" doc=selectedSyllabusDoc id="insertSyllabusForm" type="update"}}
                        <fieldset>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-2">{{> afQuickField name='alphaNumber' placeholder="ICS 101"}}</div>
                                <div class="col-sm-2">{{> afQuickField name='creditHours' placeholder="3"}}</div>
                                <div class="col-sm-2">{{> afQuickField name='prerequisites' placeholder="311 or consent"}}</div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">{{> afQuickField name='title' placeholder="Course title"}}</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-6">{{> afQuickField name='instructor' rows=2 placeholder="Name\noffice address, email"}}</div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">{{> afQuickField name='textbooks' rows=2 placeholder= "Textbook title and author, or 'none'"}}</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-6">{{> afQuickField name='objectives' rows=4 placeholder='* Students have ...\n* Students can ...\n* Students can ....'}}</div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">{{> afQuickField name='policies' rows=4 placeholder="Can be 'none'."}}</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-6">{{> afQuickField name='description' rows=4 placeholder='Insert course catalog description: http://www.catalog.hawaii.edu/courses/departments/ics.htm'}}</div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">{{> afQuickField name='grading' rows=4 placeholder="5 homework assignments (10% each)\n1 midterm (15%)\n1 final exam (15%)\n1 final project (20%)"}}</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-6">{{> afFormGroup name='learningOutcomes' type="select-checkbox"}}</div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    {{> afQuickField name='courseLearningOutcomes' rows=12 placeholder="* Learning Outcome 1\n* Learning outcome 2"}}
                                    {{> afQuickField name='schedule' rows=12 placeholder="Week 1: ...\nWeek 2: ...\nWeek 3: ..."}}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-success btn-block">Save</button>
                    {{/autoForm}}
                </div>
            {{/if}}
        </div>

        <div class="well" style="padding: 0; max-height: 100px; overflow-y: auto">
            <ul>
                {{#each editStatusList}}
                    <li>Started editing {{ syllabusName }} {{ editTimestamp }}  {{#if editFinished}} ... finished. {{/if}} </li>
                {{/each}}
            </ul>
        </div>
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  When I paste your code into a new file in my app: (a) I still get the same highlighted errors, and (b) the indentation becomes wrong!  Let me ask you this: if you take my original source code and put it into your IntelliJ, and do `Code > Reformat Code`, does it restore the correct indentation? Or does my original source have errors for you as well?

Comment: I just added a new screen image to the original question to show a much more simple file that contains the highlighting error.

Comment: @PhilipJohnson, I am sorry for replying late. I tried the code in my IntelliJ and found the real error where it was. See my new edit and paste the code. Good luck.

Comment: Genius! Fixed! Thanks!